# How can I get the http response body before sending to the browser?

Tags: .net, object, response

Is there any way I can get the body of a Response object back before it's sent down to the browser?

I'd like to do something on Page_LoadComplete to get the current response of what's about to be written to the page so I can do something with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [`Response.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx) property.

Comment: Ok, I see how it's used to modify it, usually it's an uppercase example.  How can I get the main content into a string?

Comment: I've never used it. What are you trying to accomplish? There may be a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to get a pdf export of the page.  I'm using abcpdf and it has the ability to accept a url, but when it loads the content it loses the context of the user that's logged in via forms authentication, so I'm trying to work around and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Got it.  I've got the user hitting the page I need, then using the filter to get the html, then I save that temp file and I can pass it to the pdf creator.  Thanks for the effort and the direction to Filter.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is your friend.